# Are there any websites/stack forums that talk about the internet?

Tags: discussion

I would like to know if there is a website where I can go to ask questions about the internet. Questions like: How can I delete my posts on a forum? OR: How can I change my IP address? What are some ways that I can go to ask questions or something similar to that?

Comment: http://stackexchange.com/sites lists all of the sites in the network with their descriptions.

Answer (score 7):

> How can I delete my posts on a forum?

If your question pertains to the use of a specific forum as a web application, you're in the right place on WebApps.

> How can I change my IP address?

Questions pertaining to networking, etc. are on-topic on [Super User](http://superuser.com) (and a couple of other places, but that's your best bet for everyday things).  Something of that nature probably has an answer there already, so do a search before you post.  That's a good rule of thumb on any SE site.